# How can I reset a Combobox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to reset the ComboBox to empty it,
I have one example is correct but the other one is wrong.

The two combobox bind to Enum list:

- Enum Brand:

  public enum IdentificationDeviceBrand : int
  {
      FMC = 1,
      DMM = 2,
      HTC = 3
  }
- Enum Type:

  ```
  public enum IdentificationTypes : int
  {
      TerminalEntryGate = 1,
      TerminalExitGate = 2,
      LoadingAreaEntryGate = 3,
      LoadingAreaExitGate = 4,
      IslandEntryGate = 5,
      IslandExitGate = 6
  ```

  }

I made the reset of Combobox:

- For the Type is OK

  comboType.SelectedIndex = -1;
  It will clear without any message :[image]
- But the second Combobx BRAND `comboBrand.SelectedIndex = -1;`,
  I have a message :
  [image]

XAML of the combobox BRAND:

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBrand" 
            Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource TextBoxErrorTemplate}"  
            ItemsSource="{Binding BrandEnum}"   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBrand, NotifyOnValidationError=True, TargetNullValue=''}" 
            SelectedValuePath="id" />
```

Comment: Please post your XAML markup and include a reproducible sample of your issue when asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to get rid of the text, you should remove the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` attribute:

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBrand" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding BrandEnum}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBrand, NotifyOnValidationError=True, TargetNullValue=''}" 
    SelectedValuePath="id" />
```